# Is there a NOOP in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am looking for a way to do nothing in netlogo. In other programming lanagues this is known as a no op method. Is there a way that I could do this in netlogo?

Comment: You can write a no-op procedure of your own pretty easily:  `to no-op end`.  If you only want built-in primitives, `display` or `clear-output` might be candidates, depending on your model.

Comment: nice, this works. I had a junk no-op function, and didn't think about just using `display`. Copy and paste your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm curious, though: why would you need that in NetLogo?

Comment: Its a large and complicated model and I need 100% code completeness with unit tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a no-op procedure of your own pretty easily:

```
to no-op 
end

; usage
to go
  no-op
end
```

If you only want built-in primitives, `display` or `clear-output` might be candidates, depending on what you're using in your model.

Comment: Some other no-ops: `if false []`, `while [false] []`, `repeat 0 []`, `carefully [] []`.

Comment: (`display` and `clear-output` aren't really no-ops and could be quite slow.)