# Does a no-op in netlogo slow down the model?

Tags: scala, netlogo

I use a [no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51087127/635160) function in my netlogo model to communicate intention and code-clarity to others. But I have been asked to remove it in order to speed up my model. I'm looking for all ways of speeding up the model as I already have removed all unneeded `ask turtle` blocks. The results of the `profiler` show that the `no-op` is called a lot but takes very little time.

Isn't it true that netlogo is a compiled language and thus this would be removed already by the scala compiler? Or would it give me a slight speedup to remove calls to this function?

The function block in question:

```
to no-op
end
```

Comment: NetLogo is compiled, but by the NetLogo compiler, not the Scala compiler, and I don't believe the NetLogo compiler has optimizations to remove empty procedure calls.  So there likely is some small overhead in context and call stack management.  I did think of a different way to run a no-op after your previous question:  `__ignore 0`, where `__ignore` is an undocumented prim that takes a reporter value and just ignores it.  You'd have to run some `profiler` tests to be sure, but that should take less time.  The downside is it won't be clear what it's for (can add a comment to help with that).

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082725/is-there-a-noop-in-netlogo